# Merge two lists of tuples. Desired list of tuples with two elements

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples:

`result = [(10002,), (10003,), (10004,), (10005,)...]`

`result1 = [('PL42222941176247135539240187',), ('PL81786645034401957047621964',), ('PL61827884040081351674977449',)...]`

I want merge lists.

**DESIRED OUPUT:**

`joined_result = [('PL42222941176247135539240187', 10002,), ('PL81786645034401957047621964', 10003,),('PL61827884040081351674977449', 10004,)...]`

I think about zip, but is litte wrong.
 `[(('PL42222941176247135539240187',), (10002,)), (('PL81786645034401957047621964',), (10003,)), (('PL61827884040081351674977449',), (10004,))...]`

How get desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just destructure the single-element tuples when you iterate using `zip`:

```py
joined_result = [(x, y) for ((x,), (y,)) in zip(result1, result)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems zip fails because you have a list of tuples not only a list.
In fact it creates a list of tuples of tuples.
Convert your list of tuples before passing in zip:

```
result = [x[0] for x in result]
result1 = [x[0] for x in result1]

joined_result = list(zip(result1, result))
```

or in one line:

```
joined_result = list(zip([x[0] for x in result1],[x[0] for x in result]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
result = [(10002,), (10003,), (10004,)]

result1 = [('PL42222941176247135539240187',), ('PL81786645034401957047621964',), ('PL61827884040081351674977449',)]

newResult = []

for i in range(len(result)):
    result1[i] += result[i]
    newResult.append(result1[i])
```

Warning!: it will break result1, so do result2 = result1 somewhere before the loop